# Can i develop application in Adobe Flex with AIR support?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I need to create directories in the local machine, can i do this with FLEX with AIR support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air gives you reasonable file access. Creating directories shouldn't be a problem.

See the docs for more info:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d8e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d9a

Comment: Can i do this in Flex Application, adding some AIR support to Flex... not an AIR app...

Comment: The AIR runtime provides the file system access, so you'll need to running on top of it.  And that means it will have to be an AIR application.

Comment: You need to create a new AIR application project to us the AIR features. You will want to ensure that the code for your Flex app is easily reusable in your AIR application.